# Rendering strongly-typed partial view with a different model from main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a user model and a view "AddUser" derived from it.

user model also consists a list of categories IList Categories in it.

Now When I render partial view inside AddUser view I am getting object reference not set to an instance of an object error .

User Model:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Categories> Categories{ get; set; }
    }
```

AddUser View:

```
    @Models.User
     @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {

         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
  @Html.RenderPartial("_AddCategory", Model.Categories[0]) 

    }
```

Please help.

Thanks

EDIT:
_AddCategory View:

```
@model Models.Categories


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


     <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CategoryName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CategoryDescription)
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Are there cases when the Categories object is null? You might need to check for a null value and that index zero exists before rendering the partial.

Comment: Intially when i tried to add a User,  Model.Categories is null. But when I use  @Html.Partial("_AddCategory") also giving me error, Because my _addCategory partial view is expecting Categories Model, but this will pass model 'User' as it's model.

Comment: Show us your partial view `_AddCategory`.

Comment: Can we see the stacktrace with the exception? Right off hand I see that your partial is calling `Html.BeginForm()` when the containing view has already called that method. I don't think you can call it from the partial and the containing view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried initializing the collection in the constructor?

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Categories = new List<Categories>();
    }

    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Also, why would you pass in the first Category from the Categories property to an "Add Category" partial?  Wouldn't it just be an empty Category object since you are adding a new one?

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_AddCategory", new Categories())
```

On the naming standards side, I would probably change your naming standard and name your object singular, aka Category.  Then your property becomes:

```
IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```